# What's the difference between 去 and 走？

Tags: meaning, difference

I think they both mean "to go" -- is that right?

Comment: Please provide more context or show research effort, otherwise this is a dictionary lookup question, which is not a good question. Generally, 去 means 'go' as opposed to 'come'. 走 means 'go' as opposed to 'stop'.

Comment: Alan, welcome to Chinese.SE. For future reference, please provide more context and/or steps you've taken to solve your question before asking it.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is a general reference question and doesn't clearly state where you are having difficulty understanding the difference between these two words.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.yellowbridge.com/ provides great explanations on usage, etymology, and other aspects that will help you break down each character so you can understand the differences.

去：http://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/wordsearch.php?searchMode=C&dialect=M&word=%E5%8E%BB&search=Go

To go somewhere

我去海边 (Wǒ qù hǎibiān) I'm going to the beach (with no description of how you're getting there... are you walking （走路）? are you driving (开车)? are you running (跑步)?)

---

走： http://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/wordsearch.php?searchMode=C&word=%E8%B5%B0&search=Go&dialect=M

To walk, to run, to move (vehicles), to leave

我走到海边去了 （Wǒ zǒu dào hǎibiān qùle） I walked to the beach (where 走 specifies you walked there, paired with 到 to represent the destination)

Answer (score 2):

去 means that you want to go to somewhere which is your aim.
走 It's just a kind of way to go to somewhere,you can walk(走),run,take a plane to it.